# python/django models save parmeters error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In the following code if the variable exist in the dictionary i want to save it, how to do this. This is the reason i wanted to convert `str` to variable in my previous question.

So the intention here is if there are n number of columns in the models, which i take in as a list and compare it with the request  json `di` in this case. if the variable is found then i want to assign it to company object and save it

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
  version = models.IntegerField()
  old_comp =  models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
c= Company()
li = ['version']
di = {'a':1,'version':2}
for data in li:
   if data in di:
     c.data = di[data] //gives an error since data is unknown to c
     c.save()
```

Comment: This is not clear at all. What exactly are you trying to do here? Please use proper descriptive variable names, for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code,

**DISCLAIMER**: I do not have experience with Django yet.

```
c = Company()
param_list = ['version']
param_vals = {'a':1,'version':2}
for param in param_list:
   if param in param_vals:
     setattr(c, param, param_vals[i])
c.save()
```

Comment: The call to `c.save()` should be outside the for loop - no need to hit the db B times when one is enough.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : updated answer, thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example:

```
class Company:
    def version():
        print '1.1.1'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b='version'
    a=Company()
    a.b(AttributeError: Company instance has no attribute 'b')
```

it is the same problem with your code, because the attr cannot use a variable, you can use c.version directly.